# EF Core TPC mapping and foreign key

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core

I am new to ASP NET and EF Core so this is probably a misunderstanding of how inheritance and navigation properties work in EF Core on my side.

I have a `RefreshToken` table with a FK to users. There are two types of `RefreshToken`, one for webapp only accessible to pro users and one for mobile app accessible to both pro users and "classic" users.

```csharp
    public class RefreshToken
    {
        [Key] [StringLength(64)] public string Id { get; set; }
        [StringLength(100)] public string Token { get; set; }
        public DateTime ExpiresAt { get; set; }
        public RefreshTokenType Type { get; set; } // WEB or MOBILE

        // Foreign key for user
        [StringLength(64)] public string UserId { get; set; }
        // Navigation property for user
        public BaseUserModel User { get; set; }
    }
```

`BaseUserModel` is an abstract class inherited by the two concrete user types `User` and `ProUser`.
I use TPC mapping as I want to have two user tables that are self-contained.
I added some navigation properties to conveniently get the refresh tokens that I need on the classes, but that's where I have some issues.

Parent class :

```csharp
    public abstract class BaseUserModel
    {
        [Key]
        public string UserId { get; set; }

        [Column("phone_number")]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    
        // navigation properties
        protected internal virtual ICollection<RefreshToken>? RefreshTokens { get; set; }
        public RefreshToken? MobileRefreshToken =>
            RefreshTokens?.FirstOrDefault(rt => rt.Type == RefreshTokenType.MobileApp);
    }
```

Child classes :

```csharp
    public class ProUserModel : BaseUserModel
    {
        [Column("email")] 
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public RefreshToken? WebRefreshToken => RefreshTokens?.FirstOrDefault(rt => rt.Type == RefreshTokenType.WebApp);
    }
    }

    public class UserModel : BaseUserModel
    {
        [Column("address")] 
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I would like to query a user (of any type) by `user_id` with its `MobileRefreshToken`.

---

I tried different methods to do so :

```csharp
        private async Task<BaseUserModel?> GetUserWithTokenById(string userId)
        {
            return await dbContext.BaseUsers.Include(u => u.MobileRefreshToken).SingleOrDefaultAsync(u => u.UserId == userId);
        }
```

But this does not work

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The expression 'u.MobileRefreshToken' is invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared on derived types, use casting ('t => ((Derived)t).MyProperty') or the 'as' operator ('t => (t as Derived).MyProperty'). Collection navigation access can be filtered by composing Where, OrderBy(Descending), ThenBy(Descending), Skip or Take operations.
```

If I understand correctly this means that I cannot query navigation properties directly on my abstract class. So I tried to separate the queries by user types even if that looses a bit of flexibility if I add another user class for example.

```csharp
        private async Task<BaseUserModel?> GetUserWithTokenById(string userId)
        {
            var proUser = await dbContext.ProUsers.Include(u => u.MobileRefreshToken).SingleOrDefaultAsync(u => u.UserId == userId);
            if (proUser != null)
            {
                return proUser;
            }
            return await dbContext.Users.Include(u => u.MobileRefreshToken).SingleOrDefaultAsync(u => u.UserId == userId);
        }
```

But I get the same error. I also tried by getting first the user and then trying to load the mobile token in two separate queries :

```csharp
            var user = await dbContext.Users
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync(u => u.UserId == userId);
            if (user != null)
            {
                await dbContext.Entry(user)
                    .Reference(u => u.MobileRefreshToken)
                    .LoadAsync();
                return user;
            }
// Same for pro user if null
```

But it also fails with

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The property 'UserModel.MobileRefreshToken' could not be found. Ensure that the property exists and has been included in the model.
```

Could you please help me finding a way to properly retrieve a user by id with its token ?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing it another way by retrieving the `RefreshToken` by user id with its associated user :

```csharp
await dbContext.RefreshTokens
    .Include(token => token.User)
    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(token => token.UserId == userId && token.Type == RefreshTokenType.MobileApp);
```